# Why bamboo stops build if one stage failed?

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo

I have 3 bamboo stages: testing, staging and production. All of them extract the sources, compile and run tests. In previous version of Bamboo it continued the next stage if one failed (one of test failed f.e.). In the latest version it does not go to the next stage and stops build. How can i override this behaviour in order to continue build even if one stage failed?

Output:

```
simple  17-Sep-2013 17:56:12    Failing task since return code of [c:\dev\maven3\bin\mvn.bat --batch-mode -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Bamboo\temp\CS-AND-JOB1 clean install -P envbuild -DbuildNumber=4] was 1 while expected 0
simple  17-Sep-2013 17:56:12    Parsing test results...
simple  17-Sep-2013 17:56:12    Finished task 'Maven 3.x'
simple  17-Sep-2013 17:56:12    Running post build plugin 'NCover Results Collector'
simple  17-Sep-2013 17:56:12    Running post build plugin 'Clover Results Collector'
simple  17-Sep-2013 17:56:12    Running post build plugin 'Artifact Copier'
simple  17-Sep-2013 17:56:12    Finalising the build...
simple  17-Sep-2013 17:56:12    Stopping timer.
simple  17-Sep-2013 17:56:12    Build CS-AND-JOB1-4 completed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've contacted atlassian support and they confirm it's a bug - stages should be independent. They are investigating this problem.

Comment: I can't imagine why anybody told you that. Stages are not independent, and ime never have been (not back to v3.4, anyway).

Comment: btw, we used to do exactly what you're saying you do. The Build steps for Dev, Test & Production were all **_jobs_** within a stage.  **Jobs** run independently (and potentially in parallel).  Then our deployments were separate stages so that no deployment was performed if any of the build jobs failed.

Comment: @Auspex Please find the ticket BSP-11399

Comment: ? There's no link, too hard to find. And it still doesn't make it a bug; you've been pointed to the documentation that says it's working as designed, and five years doesn't change anything.

Comment: documentation is what is desired in ideal world, and what i had is real world. See the stacktrace in the bug report

Comment: What bug report? Bamboo bug reports are prefixed with BAM-, and searching for BSP-11399 on Atlassian doesn't find anything. I begin to suspect you're just trolling. The process works _as documented_, so I really don't see your problem.

Answer (score 5):

In short, you can't override this behaviour, this is how Bamboo (and other build tools) are designed to work.

What you should be doing is:

1. Build once and save the output as an artifact which can be used by later stages
2. Test your build output by retrieving the artifact from the first stage
3. Deploy to X environment

You shouldn't be deploying to an environment if any of the preceding steps have failed, the point of a failing stage is to indicate something is not right, you should either fix broken tests or exclude them.

Comment: the stage should not be build if one of tasks or jobs is not finished or failed (f.e. tests failed). But the stages should be independent. i've added my answer.

Comment: I'm afraid this is the correct answer: stages in Bamboo are designed not to run if previous stages fails. That's the exact meaning of "build pipeline".

From [Bamboo docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/stage) 
A stage **"Must successfully complete all its jobs before the next stage in the plan can be processed."**